# react-native createMaterialTopTabNavigator with I18n based arabic Titles are not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an Arabic app, I am using forceRTL to update the views and translations.

All the things are working, except tabs Arabic titles are not getting updated.

I am using "createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createAppContainer" of react navigation.

If you have any suggestions or references for the same, please let me know.

Following is my tabs code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, Linking, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Dimensions, StatusBar, AsyncStorage, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import I18n from '../Helpers/i18n';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Upcoming from "./Upcoming.js";
import History from "./History.js";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');


const MyBookingTabs = createAppContainer(
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Upcoming: { 
      screen: Upcoming,
      navigationOptions: {
        title:I18n.t('bookingTableUpcomingText'),
      }
    },
    History: { 
      screen: History,
      navigationOptions: {
        title:I18n.t('bookingTableHistoryText'),
      }

    },
  },
    {
      tabBarPosition: 'top',
      swipeEnabled: true,
      animationEnabled: true,
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
        inactiveTintColor: '#F8F8F8',
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#f01616',
          //backgroundColor:'#000',
          shadowColor: "#fc301c",
          shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2,
          },
          shadowOpacity: 0.80,
          shadowRadius: 3.84,
          elevation: 5,
        },
        labelStyle: {
          textAlign: 'center',
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
          borderBottomColor: '#fff',
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
        },
      },
    }));


export default class MyBookingTabsComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{height:(height-150),}}>
      <MyBookingTabs screenProps={{navigationObj: this.props.screenProps.navigationObj }}/>        
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Tabs are getting updated on hot reloading to that page

Comment: I am having some problems with createMaterialTopTabNavigator(). I am also using RTL but the tabs are showing from left to right instead of right to left (I am talking about the tab labels with the indicator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using below code

title:I18nManager.isRTL ? "ملف" : "Profile"